Do the midpoints of beachball segments form an exactly elliptical shape, and how to rigorously prove that they do.
If you divide a sphere into equal segments - think apple corer or beachball - then consider opposing segments, and wrap a planar 2-D surface around those two so that the corners of the segments intersect the wrapped plane but the outter surface of the sphere is cut off - I think it becomes an elliptical tube - is there any way to prove this is an exactly elliptical shape? Another way to put it is that chords are drawn across the end points of the segments and the curved outter-most part of the sphere is removed so you have apple-slice shaped segments but like out of a peeled apple - so the outter curve only curves in the one dimension, around the apple vertically, and follows only straight chords across horizontally. Draw a line along the midpoints of infinite chords stretching across the ends of two segments - how can I prove that line traced is an ellipse?
Attempted Drawing
Sorry for the horrible drawing - also this doesn't quite depict the curved surface of the sphere being cut-off.

It's hard to understand what you write. Could you draw a sketch and post it?

If you divide a sphere into an even number of equal segments, and consider only two segments that are opposite each other, there is a plane of symmetry such that each segment is the mirror image of the other segment in that plane. The orthogonal projection of each segment onto that plane is an ellipse and each segment projects onto the same ellipse. Is that what you wanted to know?

@DavidK yes, exactly. Is there a way to show this rigorously?

Suppose we divide a sphere into an even number of equal-sized segments.
Consider two opposite segments and let $\pi_0$ be the plane between the segments such that each segment is the mirror image of the other segment in this plane.
The boundaries of the two segments on the sphere are arcs of great circles.
You would need to show that each arc bounding one of the segments lies on the same great circle as one of the arcs bounding the other segment.
This follows from the fact that the segment boundaries are $2n$ arcs spaced equally around the two poles of the sphere where all the segments meet.
The two segments are therefore bounded by two great circles. It is well known that the orthogonal projection of a circle onto a plane is an ellipse.
(You can prove this too if you don't consider it well-known enough.)
Therefore the great circles of the boundaries project onto ellipses. You then need merely prove (an argument by symmetry might be easiest) that both great circles project onto the same ellipse.
